# How do I import Okta metadata into Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, okta

I am creating an MVC5 web app that needs federated authentication.  We are using Okta.  When I create a new Web App, I choose 'Organizational Accounts' for authentication, 'On-Premises', for On-Premises Authority I put in the URL of the Okta meta data, for App ID URI I put in 'https://localhost/Okta', which is what is configured in Okta for the relying party.

When I proceed to create the solution I get an error box titled 'Enable Organizational Authentication' and inside it says 'userSelection.SecurityTokenServiceMetadata.SecurityTokenServiceDescriptor'  and that is all.  No output in my output window to help.

Can anyone help me get connected to Okta when creating a new MVC5 app in VS2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is add support for WS-Federation to your MVC5 application.

Here is a guide to [configuring WS-Federation in Okta](https://support.okta.com/articles/Knowledge_Article/29510977-Configuring-the-Okta-Template-WS-Federation-Application). Since you are using MVC5, you'll likely need to [set up WS-Federation in OWIN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/21/using-claims-in-your-web-app-is-easier-with-the-new-owin-security-components.aspx).

Comment: Actually, I was fine on the MVC side.  We had to configure Okta with WS-Federation.